# Databinding-dependency property with Relativesource

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, user-interface, mvvm

I am facing a issue in the present code.

The UI has a button, which is databound to a dependency property showbutton. Its built on the MVVM architecture.

The XAML looks like this.

```
<Grid>
.........
<Button .... IsEnabled="{Binding Path=class1.class2.showbutton,RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=views:view2, Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1}}"/>
```

...............
<\Grid>

The registered dependencyproperty looks like this

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty buttonDisplay= DependencyProperty.Register("showbutton", typeof(bool), typeof(class2), new PropertyMetadata((bool)false));

public bool showbutton
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(buttonDisplay); }
    set { SetValue(buttonDisplay, value); }
}
```

The update is called thru

```
private void UpdateProperties()
 {
   showbutton= User.CheckPrivilege("ShudEnable");        }
 }
```

the button is not getting enabled according to the showbutton. What can be the problem ? Is it possible to change showbutton value programatically . If so how ?

Comment: Can you please show your ViewModel code?

Comment: hmmm.. its pretty complex and huge. it has nested view models , which are derived from the viewmodel base..what exactly do u need?

Comment: showbutton Proeprty code.

Comment: i have added one more func!

Comment: Done any [binding debugging](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx)?

Comment: tried a lot , 3 different ways of debugging did not help either. i am basically re engineering the wole stuff. most probably m lost in the complex View models..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this DataContext.class1.class2.showbutton - Ensure that the binding path is correct. You can check for binding errors using a utility called snoop.
http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/